# JSON loaded via Flash only partially parsed on Windows 7

Tags: flash, json, windows-7

I have a flash file which loads data from JSON and parses it. It works fine expect on one machine (specs below). On that machine it loads an image URL specified in the JSON, but nothing else. I've tested with a other machines (Dell E6400, Apple MacBook Pro) and it works just fine in all browsers. I compared Windows Updates between the Dell E6400 and the Dell Optiplex 745 and they only differ by one update ([KB2525694](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2525694)) which isn't applicable for my Dell E6400.

**Machine Specs:**

- Dell Optiplex 745
- Windows 7 SP1 64-Bit
- IE9, Chrome, Firefox 4 & Safari
- Flash 10.2.159.1 & 10.3.183.10

**JSON:**

```
{
   "status":"success",
   "album":{
      "backCoverURL":"",
      "description":"A Description of this content",
      "digitalASIN":"B000UBLOP4",
      "frontCoverURL":"http://sampleurl.com/TheOnlyThingThatGetsParsed.jpg",
      "genre":"Jazz",
      "id":"175264",
      "originalReleaseDate":"1960",
      "performer":"Wes Montgomery",
      "physicalASIN":"B000NO28OO",
      "rating":"",
      "title":"Incredible Jazz Guitar of Wes Montgomery",
      "tracks":[
         {
            "digitalASIN":"B000UBJCEY",
            "durationSeconds":269,
            "id":"264475",
            "sampleURL":"http://sampleurl.com/B000UBJCEY.mp3",
            "title":"Airegin",
            "trackNum":1
         },
         {
            "digitalASIN":"B000UBDHAE",
            "durationSeconds":275,
            "id":"264476",
            "sampleURL":"http://sampleurl.com/B000UBDHAE.mp3",
            "title":"Mr. Walker (Renie)",
            "trackNum":2
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Comment: Try providing some of the code you are using to parse the JSON.  Also, if it is loading the jpg, it seems like it is at least partially succeeding in parsing the JSON.  Are you sure that the problem is with the JSON parsing and not some other issue, like maybe there's a problem with the sound card or some security setting that is preventing load of sound files?

Comment: Hello Amy, I don't have access to the code inside the Flash which parses the JSON; however, the guy who works on that is going to try seeing if preloading (before parsing) the JSON will do the trick.

Comment: @AmyBlankenship You should write an answer so I can accept it, updating the sound card drivers worked!

Comment: You can just up vote my comment if you feel a need to do something.  I was just guessing ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Amy Blankenship said in a comment to my question:

> Try providing some of the code you are using to parse the JSON. Also,
>   if it is loading the jpg, it seems like it is at least partially
>   succeeding in parsing the JSON. Are you sure that the problem is with
>   the JSON parsing and not some other issue, like maybe there's a
>   problem with the sound card or some security setting that is
>   preventing load of sound files?

It in fact was a bad sound card.